# Installation of Azure Functions to visual studio 2015

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Functions. I am trying to install Azure functions 2.9.6 version. I am able to install it, but still cannot see it in visual studio templates.
I have updated my visual studio to update 3. Earlier, I tried version 3 too, but its still not fixed. Where I am getting it wrong.This is the snapshot of my installed programs. [image: This is the snapshot of my installed programs.]

Edited:
I tried to convert the azure function code into cs code for running it, but failed with errors:
[image]

Comment: You don't see azure function project template?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. I am able to install it without any errors, but can't see azure functions template nor could open .funproj file.

Comment: Have the same issue, tried a thousand things and still doesn't work. very frustrated. Now looking how to get functions to work on VS 2017 tools but it's not that straightforward either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the blog post [Azure Functions Tools Roadmap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/14/azure-functions-tools-roadmap/).

The new approach for C# Azure Functions will be based on class libraries. The Azure Functions Preview tooling for VS 2015 has a known incompatibility with Azure SDK Version 3.0.0. If it has ever been installed on the machine, the tooling will fail to work correctly.

We instead recommend that you use class libraries to author your functions. You can do this today using VS 2015 or VS 2017, but our new tooling will make it even easier. See the blog post [Publishing a .NET class library as a Function App](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/03/16/Publishing-a-.NET-class-library-as-a-Function-App.html).

Comment: I tried to convert it into cs code as described in the link, but it gives error. Snapshot is attached with the question.

Comment: You need to add NuGet packages for packages like Newtonsoft.Json. This is covered in the blog post.

Comment: I don't quite understand, how I can publish the project as a Function App using VS 2015. What it does is publishes as a generic App Service and I don't see the app in the Azure Functions list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you follow the steps on [this site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/)?

Notice, that it is not possible to use it with VS2017. Look at this comment:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know. I followed the same link, and am trying it with VS 2015 update 3.

Comment: Okay, I think the problem is on the first steps of the getting started. I hope it's not rude, but I must ask the following question: Do you have installed the "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" for VS 2015 Update 3? Look at this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSkzY.png

Comment: Yeah, I have installed that.

Comment: Perhaps, you should create an issue for that here: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue